# Coldfusion 8 - cfquery insert statement times out

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, insert, timeout, cfquery

I'm building a script that uses cfhttp to reads a delimited log files.  These log files tend be rather large so when I try to INSERT the data from the logfile into a table I've created, my cfquery insert statement times out.

So, my idea to get around this is to insert maybe 200 - 300 records at a time and then somehow refresh the insert statement timer and then import the next set of 200-300 records.

I'm not completely sure how to accomplish this.

Anyone every dealt with importing thousands of entries from a logfile?  how did you overcome the timeout in the cfquery tag.

Comment: I've tried the BULK INSERT command but I'm having a problem grabbing the file that is stored locally. I get the following error:


Error Executing Database Query.  
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Could not bulk insert because file 'C:\websites\mywebsite.com\htdocs\files\demo.txt' could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this would work for you, but for the core task of getting the log file data into the database I would bypass the step where ColdFusion parses the data altogether.

Have a look at doing it directly from SQL.

1. First copy your file locally, perhaps using `<cfftp/>`
2. Then, treat your log file like a CSV file and [write a SP](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) you can execute via CF that just reads your log data into a temp table. This should be quick and avoid any timeouts.
3. You can then have a seperate step (in SQL again, perhaps) to reorganise your data once it is in the temp table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Are you saying i can use BULK INSERT inside of cfquery tag?  I'll give it a try now.  What i was doing is using cfhttp to read the file into a query object. then i wrapped a cfquery insert into command with a cfoutput query command.  It does the insert, but like i said it times out.

Answer (score 0):

First check it's the db timing out and not the http request. Are you inserting 1 rec at a time inside a cfloop? And have you got an index for the table you are inserting into? Try inserting multiple records in one insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the file loaded into a session variable, you can parse rows at a time using the startrow and endrow attributes of cfloop each call. You would then set up your script to set a counter, do the first pass, update the counter, and then send the information to your process again using cfhttp, passing in the udpated counter. The process will then just parse those rows and do the inserts.

For large amounts of data, and depending on the database, you may consider creating a stored procedure that you can pass the whole chunk in at one time, like as XML. Your sproc would then do a single insert statement into your table from the XML field.

That will speed up the processing and will not cause CF to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Cold Fusion can pass the Batch Insert commands that SQL server uses, you just need to be sure that function is allowed on the dB server you are using.  I suggest bringing the file in locally and use the Batch Insert capabilities of SQL server.